# CIFilter available in iOS?

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics, core-image, cifilter

I want to know for sure before I start implementing my own filters (probably using opengl ES) but are the [CIFilters](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/) available on iOS? Anything similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CIFilters are not currently available in the SDK. If it's something you'd wish to see, you should [file a request with Apple](http://bugreporter.apple.com).

Answer (score 3):

Update: CIFilters are now [included in iOS 5](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cifilter).