# Iphone Core Image Filter

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm wondering about that, I have seen into many sites describing that Core Image filters on Iphone doesn't support by Apple. But I have seen Core image filter in Core Animation example page on the Apple developer site. 
just look at here [Iphone OS Reference Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20100831121232/http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006085-SW1), you will see that example on this page

```
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBloom"];
[filter setDefaults];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
```

Any description for that would be appreciated.

Comment: ...so what is your question? Do you want to know if Apple actually supports Core Image filters on the iPhone? Do you want to know what this particular filter does? Do you want an explanation of how to use it? Or something else?

Comment: Absolutelly i'm looking these answers but i took my question's answer. Apple doesn't support core image filters on iphone yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core Image is not available on the iPhone.  From the [CATransition Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catransition/1412506-filter), when talking about the filter property:

> While the CATransition class exposes
>   this property, Core Image is not
>   available in iPhone OS. Currently the
>   filters available for this property
>   are undefined.

Also, in the [CALayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410901-filters), when talking about the filters property:

> While the CALayer class exposes this
>   property, Core Image is not available
>   in iPhone OS. Currently the filters
>   available for this property are
>   undefined.

As Cory points out, this guide was written for the Mac and modified to apply to the iPhone.  Unfortunately, they left in an example that only works on the Mac.

See also the questions:

- [How can I use CIFilter in iPhone OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164797/how-can-i-use-cifilter-in-iphone-os)
- [CIFilter available in the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483039/cifilter-available-in-the-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Brad, thank you for your answer. Actually I'm looking good tutorials or books about the Iphone Core Animation, I would like to learn more detail and also more examples. Usually, many Core Animation books are describing Iphone core animation subject only last chapters.

I think apple documentation insufficient about this topic.
Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Check out Marcus Zarra and Matt Long's Core Animation book: http://www.amazon.com/Core-Animation-Simplified-Techniques-Development/dp/0321617754/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1264225492&sr=8-1 iPhone-specific content is interwoven throughout the text.  However, the reason why you don't see much dedicated to Core Animation on the iPhone is because it's nearly identical between the two platforms (the Core Image filters being one of the few differences).

Answer (score 1):

You're quoting the Core Animation Programming Guide which was originally written for Mac OS X and has since been updated to include iPhone OS.  Not all code samples will work on both OS's.  You'll find this to be true in many of Apple's programming guides.

Take a look at the [revision history](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004628-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

Core Image is available for iOS 5, currently in beta. while not all the Mac Filters are included thus far, there's still a good selection.