# How to add CIFilter to CALayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

I am new to core animation , i add some layers to my view and add image to it.
Now i want to give blur effect to my layer

But i don't know how to make CIFilter and add it.
I go through the related questions 
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164797/how-can-i-use-cifilter-in-iphone-os)  [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483039/cifilter-available-in-the-iphone-sdk)

---

My code is given below (Shows compilation error)

```
#import < UIKit/UIKit.h >
#import < QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h >
#import < CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h >


@interface T_CALayerPart3_View : UIView {

    CALayer *_layer1;
    CALayer *_layer2;
    CALayer *_layer3;
    CALayer *_layer4;
    CALayer *_layer5;
    CIFilter *_filter;    //<----- error here[Expected specifier -qualifier -list before CIFilter]

    CATransform3D *_rotate, *_scale;

}
@end
```

Give me some suggestion. Your suggestion is important to me. Don't leave the page without any  Answer/ comment.

[sorry for my poor English]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no CIFilter in iPhone OS. There is CAFilter but it is a ***private API*** so using it on AppStore apps means rejection. If you already know what images you will use, you could create the blurred image in the first place.

See [*How to implement a box or gaussian blur on iPhone*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140117/how-to-implement-a-box-or-gaussian-blur-on-iphone) on how to implement a Gaussian blur filter "legally".

See [*CAFilter — iPhone Development Wiki*](http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=CAFilter#Applying_filters_to_layers) on how to apply a blur filter on a CALayer using the ***private*** CAFilter class.

Comment: As per your second answer(Wiki) , when i am trying to make an object of CAFilter  [CAFilter *_filter ; ] it shows same error .

Comment: @new: You need to declare CAFilter yourself how it is a "private API™".

Comment: @Kenny Can you explain it, [declaring CAFilter].

Comment: @new: That means you need to add a `@interface CAFilter : NSObject @end` to the file you're going to use.

Comment: Thank you for your nice reply. Its its my first time to get a reply like this.

Comment: Anyones app been removed from the app store for using CAFilter?